# Plotting Multiple plots in a single plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the graph for 25 samples, I am able to plot it individually but I am unable to plot them all in single plot. I need 8 samples plot with line and different colors, 8 samples with dotted lines and different colors and also the remaining with dashed lines with different colors. I would like to plot all of them in one graph.

Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xs = []
ys = []
for i in range(25):
    subregion_average = np.mean(read_data['sub_region'][i], axis =(0,1))
    wavelength = read_data['wavelength'][i]
    xs.append(wavelength)
    ys.append(subregion_average)
for i in range(len(ys)):
    colours=['r','g','b','k','r','c','m','y']
    if i<=7:
      ax.plot(xs[i], ys[i], 'k--', linewidth = 2)
    else if 8<=i<=15:
      ax.plot(xs[i], ys[i], 'k:', linewidth = 2)
    else:
      ax.plot(xs[i], ys[i], 'k', linewidth = 2)
      
    ax.set_xlim(min(wavelength), max(wavelength))
    ax.tick_params(labelsize = 12)
    ax.set_title('Average Spectrum Calibrated sample', fontsize = 14, weight = 'bold')
    ax.set_ylabel('Reflectance', fontsize = 14)
    ax.set_xlabel('Wavelength in nm', fontsize = 14)
    ax.grid(True)
```

############

SOLUTION: I got the solution for it, it might not be high level but this is how I want the logic and got all graphs in single plot. Thanks for the inputs.

```
colours =  ['r','g','b','k','r','c','m','y','r','g','b','k','r','c','m','y','r','g','b','k','r','c','m','y','g','k']
for i in range(len(ys)):
    if i<=7:
       plt.plot(xs[i], ys[i], 'k--', c=colours[i], linewidth = 2)
    elif 8<=i<=15:
       plt.plot(xs[i], ys[i], 'k:', c=colours[i], linewidth = 2)
    else:
       plt.plot(xs[i], ys[i], 'k', c=colours[i], linewidth = 2) 
    plt.xlim(min(wavelength), max(wavelength))
    plt.tick_params(labelsize = 12)
    plt.title('Average Spectrum Calibrated sample', fontsize = 14, weight = 'bold')
    plt.ylabel('Reflectance', fontsize = 14)
    plt.xlabel('Wavelength in nm', fontsize = 14)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12,12)
    plt.savefig("Spectrum_Plots",dpi=500)
```

---

Comment: You can use a  cycler to create different combinations of colors/line styles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259659/8881141

Comment: You create a new figure every iteration.

Comment: You should first create the grid of subplots with the layout you want by using `plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)`. Then you can loop through the array of `Axes` that you can `zip` with the lists of corresponding variables to plot, colors and line styles with `zip(axs.flat, xs, ys, colors, linestyles)` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66163604/14148248). Or you could use an indexing approach using `enumerate(axs.flat)` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909342/14148248), or a cycler as suggested by Mr. T.